# UWP 10 (xaml) - MVVM - Listbox with Nested Observable Collection

Tags: c#, mvvm, listbox, uwp, observablecollection

So first time. Also, im not a programmer, more of a scripter / designer.

Anyways. I have a Listbox that uses an observable collection for its itemsSource. Adding new entries and saving them is not an issue, all of that works. Making changes (through INotifyChanged etc) all works fine.

XAML:

```
 <ListBox x:Name="ProjectsListedView"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding Companies.ProjectsListed}"
                 SelectedValue="{Binding ProjectsName}"
                 SelectedIndex="-1"
                 SelectionMode="Extended">
 </Listbox>
```

This part works. (except for the selectedvalue / index)

ProjectsListed is an observable collection that is part of companies. 
So the idea is. When I select a company.. The listed projects for that company appear. This works as intented.

However.. For the life of me, I cant get "selected item" to work properly.

What I have attempted:

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
```

and even:

```
<Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

both didnt work. Anyways. The odd thing is.. There is a selection being done.
When the listbox is created and the collection is added (from an xml file). I am able to select an item.. and get the information from the selected item into textboxes. example:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.ProjectName, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=ProjectsListedView}"
                 Style="{StaticResource TB_M}"
                 Width="450" 
                 Name="ProjectNameInput" 
                 PlaceholderText=""
                 Grid.Row="0"/>
```

So what is the issue:
The "selected item" cant be deleted. `

```
public async static Task DeleteProjectFile(this Company companies)
    {
        var file = await GetCompanyFile(companies.CompanyName);
        if (file == null)
        {
            var folder = await GlobalFolder();
            file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(companies.CompanyName + GlobalFileExtension, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }
        Projects project = new Projects();

        companies.ProjectsListed.Remove(project);
    }
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction (examples would be much appreciated). If more code is required, please ask. As previously mentioned, this is my first question / post.

Kind regards.

Comment: What is this line supposed to do? `companies.ProjectsListed.Remove(project);`  At a glance, `project` is a newly created object, and is not present in the observablecollection, so this line would simply throw an exception.

Comment: Supposedly it should remove the project from the list / xmlfile. Strangely enough, there was a time it worked (prior to me heading into listboxes). Therefor I never looked back at it.  Companies = the "parent", ProjectsListed = the observablecollection & remove = the command used for removing items from an array / collection.. Also, I dont get any exception thrown when I do press the button.. Nor does it crash or anything.. So..

Comment: So according to @kennyzx 's comment, have you updated and resolved your issue? If you still have issues, did you have a [mcve] for testing by us?

Comment: Fixed the issue, or at least this one. The comment did not really help that much, had a friend take a look. Feel free to close this (soz, I cant seem to find out where / how to do that).

Comment: @SdNA, you can share your solution as the answer and mark it. Or delete this thread by yourself.  See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42265/how-can-i-delete-my-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix most of this.

The deletion part thanks to the help of a friend and a little bit from the comment placed by kennyzx

```
public async static Task DeleteProjectFile(this Company companies)
    {
        var file = await GetCompanyFile(companies.CompanyName);
        if (file == null)
        {
            var folder = await GlobalFolder();
            file = await folder.CreateFileAsync(companies.CompanyName + GlobalFileExtension, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        }

            companies.ProjectsListed.RemoveAt(0);
    }
```

It might not delete the selected, but at the very least it is deleting an entry.

And a fix for storing the "selected item", might be a bit of a weird way, but I just create an extra xml serialize on

```
public async void ProjectsListedView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
```

in a different location. And each time the "frame" is being called, it reloads this. 
The actual selected setter (highlight) however, is not working, but all in all, its fixed.

Thanks to all that attempted to help out.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem lies here: `SelectionMode="Extended"`.

If you take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_ListBox_SelectionMode) (if the anchor doesn't work, search for SelectionMode), you can find this line:

> When SelectionMode is Multiple or Extended, use the SelectedItems property to get the items that are selected.

If you don't need multiple selection, change the `SelectionMode` to `Single`. Otherwise, you need to use the `SelectedItems` property instead of `SelectedItem`.

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your response. Sadly this does not work. It feels like uwp is "faking" the selection. Like it shows it, it shows the information inside the observable collection, but that's it. My company listbox (based on an MRU) works fine. But thats not an observable collection nor nested.